# How to make only specific rows be visible in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a SQL database and I only want to make some  rows of my `DataGridView` visible. I want to compare the ID of the row (which is saved in index 0) to the ID of the user currently logged in (which I have saved as `userid`), and if it's the same, I want to make only that row visible.

I have tried numerous things but none of them seem to change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you set the DataSource of your DataGridView?. Probably filtering the source is the best path. But without code this question will be probably closed

Comment: Use a WHERE clause in your query.

Comment: if you cannot modify SQL query as was suggested by @LarsTech then go with `LINQ` in your CS code

Comment: If you need to keep all the rows, but only show some to a specific user based on a condition, you can filter the `DataTable.DefaultView` (which return a DataView object) and use it as the `DataGridView.DataSource`. The filter is simply the conditin without the `WHERE` part => `"ID = [User.ID]"`. See: [DataView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter)